# Determining the value of a constant in a multicalc exercise regarding a tangent and a curve

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, curves, tangent-line

Let the line that goes through the points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,2)$ be a tangent to the curve defined by $x^2-2y^2=C\in\mathbb{R}$. I need to determine the value of $C$. My strategy thus far has been to find the point of intersection $(a,b)$ and then use that to determine the value of $C$. Thus far I have that  $ax-2by=C$ and $a+2b=0$. I don't really know what to do here, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need derivatives. Note that the equation for your line is
$$y=1-x$$
So you need to find the intersection point. When replacing this into the conic equation, you have
$$x^2-2(1-x)^2= C$$
Therefore
$$x^2-4x+2+C=0$$
You can now solve for the tangent points and draw conclusions.

Comment: $x^2-2y^2$ isn’t a circle. If it were, then there would be two solutions to the problem. It is, however, a conic section, so a tangent line still intersects the curve in a single point.

Comment: Sorry, of course it's an hyperbole. I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t happen to recognize that the curve is a conic section, allowing you to solve this by examining the discriminant of a quadratic, you can proceed more generically as follows: If a line is tangent to a curve, it is orthogonal to the curve’s normal at the point of tangency. The direction of the normal to this curve is given by the gradient $\nabla(x^2-2y^2) = (2x,-4y)$, the direction vector of the line is $(1,0)-(-1,2)=(2,-2)$ and the orthogonality condition can be expressed via a dot product: $$(2x,-4y)\cdot(2,-2)=4x+8y=0.$$ The intersection of this line with the given one is the point of tangency to the curve, and $C$ is then found by plugging the coordinates of this point into $x^2-2y^2$.